# expo build (IOS & android) and Expo publish error

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've been trying to build an app I was working for for the last month, but it doesn't want to work when I use the commands:

expo build:android
expo build:ios
expo publish
But my app runs normally on development mode, on both real android and IOS devices

Samsung galaxy s8
Iphone 9s

with no errors or anything.

```
expo build:android
Checking if there is a build in progress...

Request failed with status code 500
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\FiercePC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: In case of 500 error, the service is temporarily suspended due to heavy server usage, or the problem is caused by an abnormality of the server.
This could be an error in the server script. It seems good to try again after a while.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, I believe that this error has to do with the app.json file
Mine worked after I removed the field owner
for some reason the docs recommends to add it to publish the project, but it didn't let me add one

Comment: @YoussefEll you beauty! That worked for me as well. Thanks so much for following back up.

Comment: @isick No worries bro, good luck

Answer (score 3):

Remove `"owner"` field from your `app.json` file.

[Full credit goes to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208554/expo-build-ios-android-and-expo-publish-error#comment101013856_57208554), I just think this should be posted as an answer, as it's easy to miss in comments section.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've just changed my bundlerIdentifier
From this
**"bundlerIdentifier": "com.example.app.appName"**
To this
**"bundlerIdentifier": "com.example-app.appName"**
and it worked for me.